# Read the 3 next lines in python file

Tags: python

I want to read the 3 next lines in a file but from a given point

If a user is in the phonebook I display the user and the 3 next lines -> code snippet

```
import re


phonebook_rule = re.compile(r'\'\D{3,6}\'\'\D{3,13}\'\'\d{10}\'')

def myFunction(phonebooke):
    
    print(phonebooke)
    
    if begin == 1:
        
        firstname = input('enter a firstname:')
        lastname = input('enter a lastname:')
        phone = input('enter a number:')
        
        
        imp = (f'\'{firstname}\'\'{lastname}\'\'{phone}\'')
        if phonebook_rule.match(imp):
            
            phbook = open('Phonebook','a')
            
            phbook.write('Fristname: ' + firstname + '\n')
            phbook.write('Lastname: ' + lastname + '\n')
            phbook.write('Phone: ' + phone + '\n')
            phbook.close()
            
        else:
            print('Not a good format')
    elif begin == 2:

search = input('Search a user:')
cnt = 1
            
        if search in phbook.read():

            print('This user is in the phonebook')
            while True:
                print(phbook.readlines())
                cnt += 1
                if cnt == 3:
                    break
       else:
           print('No user found')
               
     else:
         print('nothing')

begin = int(input('Chose a number 1 to 4:'))

print(myFunction(begin))
```

Don't know how to do this , especially the part when I need to start from "search" input and then display the 3 other lines...

Edit: [image: nothing]

That's the only things I get with readlines()

[image: nothing2]

There's a user called Matt in my phonebook or maybe I did something wrong ?

Comment: Can you post the full code (i.e. the code to initialize `phbook`)?

Comment: @n004rp It looks like you're looking for `readline()` instead of `readlines()` Try that substitution and see if the code does what you want.

Comment: It display nothing for the readline() it says the user is in the Phonebook but without displaying the 3 next lines and the user name

Comment: I think the problem is that you called phbook.read() and then called the readline() or readlines() method; the file object has run out of text after you called read the first time

Comment: How did you load phbook?

Comment: I deleted the .read() so there's only readline() it returns "none" maybe cause of the print and no return statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to reinitialize the file object. I suspect that this is will do what you're looking for.

```
    search = input('Search a user:')
    
    phbook.close()
    phbook = open('Phonebook','r')
    for line in phbook:
        line = line.strip()
        if search in line:
            print('This user is in the phonebook')
            print(line)   # print the line where you found the string
            for _ in range(2):
                print(phbook.readline()) # print the next 2 lines
            break
    else:
        print('No user found')
```

Comment: It dispays me "No user found" even if there's is a user in the phonebook idk why

Comment: @n004rp It might help to reinitialize the file object in "read" mode; see my latest edit

Comment: @n004rp Great! If that solved your problem, then please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of my answer.